# phpmailer: how to debug only if recipient is accepted and email delivered

Tags: php, debugging, smtp, response, phpmailer

I have the usual phpmailer configuration as follows:

```
try {
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;  

    $mail->isSMTP();                                            
    $mail->Host       = $myhost;
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   

    $mail->Username   = $myusername;                     
    $mail->Password   = $mypassword; 
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;

    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'TLS';  
    $mail->Port       = 587;   

    $receiver = $receiver_arr[$r-1];
    $mail->setFrom($sender, $sender_full_denomination);
    $mail->addAddress($receiver, $receiver_full_denomination); 
    $mail->addReplyTo($sender, $replyto_full_denomination);


    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  
    $mail->Subject = $mail_subject;
    $mail->Body    = $mail_body;
    $mail->AltBody = $mail_body_alt;
    $mail->AddEmbeddedImage($file_path_1, $cid_1, $img_name_1);
    $mail->AddEmbeddedImage($file_path_2, $cid_2, $img_name_2);

    $mail->send();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    // ------ do some stuff with Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}<br>";
}
```

Ii is perfectly working, but that verbose debug output is impossible to manage with hundreds of email to send, and nevertheless I need to check two things (and possibly store them into a variable so that I can record results in the db):

1. if the recipient's email server is active;
2. if the email is delivered to recipient's mailbox or if for any reason is bounced or refused (non existing recipient, mailbox full or whatever);

All that in procedural way, not OOP, since this is a committer decision.

How can I reach that?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose exactly what you want to do with the debug output by [injecting a callable into the `Debugoutput` property](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/src/PHPMailer.php#L403). For example:

```
$mail->Debugoutput = function($str, $level) {
    echo "debug level $level; message: $str";
};
```

You can do anything you like in there (meaning that it's *entirely* up to you), including resetting output between messages or recipients, logging to files, saving info in a database, etc.

No idea what you mean about being procedural; this is entirely OO, and has nothing to do with committers.

BTW, you're setting `SMTPSecure` twice. The first time is enough.

Comment: String $str gets the content of each single line of message or it gets the entire set of messages between client and server and back?